# Html onclick does not seem to work in echo PhP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am a beginner in PHP. Basically I am trying to add a button called "delete" to the row of the table. However:

1. the button name even though I have called it 'delete', it still shows up as 'Submit'
2. The onclick function doesn't seem to work in echo.(I have look at other methods but doesn't seem to understand or match up with what I intend to do)

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Updated: I have already fix problem 1. however I could not get problem 2 onClick function to delete any table data when i press the button any help would be appreciated.

Update 1:  Admin.php code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head> <!--inseart script here -->
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>  <!-- jquery script -->
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="js/func_submit_msg.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" id= "message_form"><br> <!-- br break new line -->


    <input type="submit" id= "submit_form" onclick = "submit_msg()">

    <div id="result"></div>


    <table border= "1" style="width: 100%">
        <!--create top table -->
        <tr> <!--tr defines a row --> <!-- define row 1 -->
            <th> No </th> <!-- th defines a header cell--> 
            <th> messages </th>
            <th> action </th>
        </tr>
         <!-- row 2 : display results onwards and creates dynamically -->   
        <!-- input fields at the bottom -->


            <?php
                include "connect.php";
                $get_data2admin = $db->query("SELECT ID,message FROM test_table_1");


                if( $get_data2admin->num_rows >0 ){ //if selected rows is more than zero
                    while($row_msg = $get_data2admin->fetch_assoc()){
                        //insert html tag table inside echo

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row_msg['message']. "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"."<input  type='submit' name='delete' id='delete_row' value='Delete' onClick='Delete()'>"."</td>"; //new updated line


                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }

            ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update 1:  func_submit_msg.js (would probably rename this file to global.js to avoid confusion)

```
//this is a function file to submit message to database, use include before calling function

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#submit_form').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
message_form = $('#message_form').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit_data.php",
    data: {message: message_form},
        success: function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
        },
        error:function(err){
           //handle your error
           alert('did not work');
        }
    });
  });

  $function Delete() {
$('input[name="delete"]').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var show_id=$(this).attr('id') //to grab id of element

  if(confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete")){
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "delete.php",
      data: {show_id},
        success: function() {

        },
        error:function(err){
           //handle your error
           alert('did not work');
        }
      });
});
});
});
});
```

Original message:

The main button code is in the admin.php page together with the onclick function:

admin.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <!--inseart script here -->
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>  <!-- jQuery script -->
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="js/func_submit_msg.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" id= "message_form"><br> <!-- br break new line -->


    <input type="submit" id= "submit_form" onclick = "submit_msg()">

    <div id="result"></div>


    <table border= "1" style="width: 100%">
        <!--create top table -->
        <tr> <!--tr defines a row --> <!-- define row 1 -->
            <th> No </th> <!-- th defines a header cell--> 
            <th> messages </th>
            <th> action </th>
        </tr>
         <!-- row 2 : display results onwards and creates dynamically -->   
        <!-- input fields at the bottom -->


            <?php
                include "connect.php";
                $get_data2admin = $db->query("SELECT ID,message FROM test_table_1");


                if( $get_data2admin->num_rows >0 ){ //if selected rows is more than zero
                    while($row_msg = $get_data2admin->fetch_assoc()){
                        //insert html tag table inside echo

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row_msg['message']. "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"."<input  type='submit' name='delete' id='delete_row' onclick =' '>"."</td>"; //in this scenario the indents ' and " matters

                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }

            ?>
    </table>

</body>
```

Below is the javascript file called func_submit_msg.js which has the ajax delete function (the second function of the code)

```
//this is a function file to submit message to database, use include     before calling function

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit_form').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
message_form = $('#message_form').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit_data.php",
    data: {message: message_form},
        success: function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
        },
        error:function(err){
           //handle your error
           alert('did not work');
        }
    });
  });




$('#delete_row').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var show_id=this.id //to grab id of element

if(confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete")){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "delete.php",
    data: {show_id},
        success: function() {

        },
        error:function(err){
           //handle your error
           alert('did not work');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

A delete.php file that suppose to delete the row by id element

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

if($_POST['show_id'])
{
    $delete_id=$db->query("DELETE FROM test_table_1 WHERE ID='$show_id'");
}

if ($insert_data === TRUE ){
echo "Delete successfully";
} else {
echo "Error delete: " . $insert_data . "<br>" . $db->error;
}

$db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For point 1:

```
<input  type='submit' name='delete' id='delete_row' onclick ='Delete(<?php echo $row_msg['id']?>)' value="Delete">
```

For point 2:

```
<input  type='submit' name='delete' id='delete_row' onclick ='Delete(<?php echo $row_msg['id']?>)'>
```

Comment: Do not understand? i have already done that sorry but it still doesnt allow me to delete. point 2 code doesnt fix the issue?

Comment: you forgot a semicolon there

Comment: @hanshenrik The ending semicolon isn't necessary on single statements.

Answer (score 0):

1.change delete button like this

```
<input  type='submit' name='delete' id='delete_row' onclick ='Delete(<?php echo $row_msg['id']?>)'>
```

2. assuming that u have any unique id so i mentioned in onclick function change it if you have other name

   ```
   function Delete(id)
   {
       var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
       if(x)
       {

    $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: {id:id},
   success: function() {

   },
   error:function(err){
      //handle your error
      alert('did not work');
   }
   });
    });
       }
   ```

Comment: @Vicky if i use value="delete" it will give an error 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'delete' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in

should if have been value='delete' instead a single ' ' ?

Comment: @peekaboo you r mention `<input type="submit" id= "submit_form" onclick = "submit_msg()">` where is `submit_msg function` and and the error u r mentioning is something like php error i dont think it will come in `HTML`

Comment: @vikcy i think u forgot as i m echoing out in php hence the input value should have been 'delete' yup that changes the name to delete but ajax function still doesn't work

Comment: @Vicky yes i realise i did not call the submit_msg() function in the func_submit_msg.js but i dont think it matter? as it was a code redundancy there. As it still work initially and could submit messages before this. I never include the code for submit_data.php as it wasnt the issue here

Comment: @Naruto how do i put a unique elemet id for the row so that i can delete them?

Comment: @peekaboo yes you have to put an id which will be unique for each row

Comment: @Vicky can i put the id i got from mysql database? so i put <input  type='submit' name='delete' id='$row_msg['ID']' value='delete'

Would this be correct?
Update this did not work:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: @peekaboo just updated code check it out hope this will work if any problem let me know

Comment: @Vicky your code this part, row_msg['id'] the 'id' is causing an issue . The error is        Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: i was just taken that as an example as i said change it to your db `id` if you have any

Comment: if you don't have any unique id how would you delete any row without saying mysql to which row has to delete

Comment: @Vicky mysql database i gave an id called ID however when replacing that, the editor highlight that error and when i run my code it still give Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: always try to take a unique id in any  `mysql table`  in future

Comment: @Vicky was my way of taking a unique id wrong? didnt i took a unique ID?

Comment: how can say that without seeing your db table , and unique id must be `auto-incremented` so everytime the data will insert it will save with an auto-incremented value thanks!! and byee..

Comment: @Vicky yes my database table is autoincremented, alright thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

Take unique id as ID from SQL result and use jQuery code for delete row as:

```
$('input[name="delete"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var show_id=$(this).attr('id');
    //...
});
```

I hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: the message does not get deleted